# Downloading multiple files from a concurrent TCP server: strange results and "Pipe Error"

Tags: python, sockets, tcp, concurrency, subprocess

I am almost finished building a concurrent (process based) python TCP server which accepts continuous commands from a client. The client can download a file from the server.

As of right now, the client can successfully download an image of the glorious Bob Ross ('bob.jpg') by typing 'DL bob.jpg'. This sends the string bob.jpg using str[3:] as input for the download command.

A client can download the image 'bob.jpg' a seemingly infinite amount of times. If the client downloads the file 'Battlefield.mp3', the file successfully downloads, however the download command will not work again unless another command has been typed in between (such as DIR). In other words: If the client tries to download 'Battlefield.mp3' twice or once and then 'bob.jpg', an error is raised.

It is strangely specific to Battlefield.mp3 - I will try to upload another mp3 and test this out to see if I can reproduce and edit in my results.

The way my server download code works is: It first calls socket.send() to send a message containing the filename and the filesize of the file to be downloaded. The string sent is something like "bob.jpg|93174" and my client parses it (using split("|")) and uses those as variables. The server will read exactly the amount of bytes that the file is downloading and the client will write exactly the same amount (and also call the file the same filename).

client

```
#~~~~~DOWNLOAD~~~~~#
    elif nextCommand.find("DL") == 0 or nextCommand.find("dl") == 0:

        sendPath = nextCommand[3:]
        print "Attempting download using filepath as: " , sendPath

        fileInfo = s.recv(1024)
        print "Download Request Acknowledged from server" # , fileInfo
        if fileInfo.find("Error") == 0:
            print "Error Opening File"
        else:
            if fileInfo:
                fL = fileInfo.split("|")
                dlPath = fL[0]
                fileSize = fL[1]
                f = open(dlPath, 'wb+') #Download Target Path
                print "Saving file as:" , f.name
                print "Recieved File Size as:" , fileSize
                fSize = int(fileSize) 
                fileContent = s.recv(fSize)
                f.write(fileContent)
                print "Download Complete"
                f.close()
```

server

```
elif data.find("DL") == 0 or data.find("dl") == 0:

        printTime(data)

        fPath = data[3:]

        try:

            file = open(fPath,'rb+')
            print "Opened File: " , file.name
            fSize = os.path.getsize(fPath)
            print "File Size: " , fSize
            strSize = str(fSize)

            seq = (file.name, strSize)
            msg = "|".join(seq)                 
            clientsocket.send(msg)
            fileContent = file.read(fSize)
            clientsocket.send(fileContent)
            file.close()            
            print "Sent and closed file"
        except IOError:
            msg = "Error Opening File"
            print msg
            clientsocket.send(msg)

            continue
```

client out:

```
Attempting download using filepath as:  Battlefield.mp3
Download Request Acknowledged from server
Saving file as: Battlefield.mp3
Recieved File Size as: 5410198
Download Complete
Enter Command: dl download.txt
Sending Command: dl download.txt

Attempting download using filepath as:  download.txt
Download Request Acknowledged from server
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cli.py", line 74, in <module>
    f = open(dlPath, 'wb+') #Download Target Path
TypeError: file() argument 1 must be encoded string without NULL bytes, not str
```

server out:

```
Opened File:  Battlefield.mp3
File Size:  5410198
Sent and closed file
Recived  dl download.txt from:  ('127.0.0.1', 34858)  |  2015-12-06 21:05:15.453932
Opened File:  download.txt
File Size:  33
Error Opening File
Process Process-16:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 232, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 88, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "serv.py", line 115, in handler
    clientsocket.send(msg)
error: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

edit:

Trying it with a different mp3 gives me a different error:

```
Attempting download using filepath as:  unity.mp3
Download Request Acknowledged from server
Saving file as: unity.mp3
Recieved File Size as: 3985398
Download Complete
Enter Command: dl unity.mp3
Sending Command: dl unity.mp3

Attempting download using filepath as:  unity.mp3
Download Request Acknowledged from server
Saving file as: êa¾è¸Ôq·s¡
                          Recieved File Size as:
õ¯vd22û¥$#P®Gµ7ýÿõ-¶ÛXÝ^m±ÆçìÎÅéM¤Vp6OK¦ÿûDwXVá
                                               +pU«
§n
]a[æ ­ÁL,0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cli.py", line 77, in <module>
    fSize = int(fileSize)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '\x85\x97\xf5\xafvd\x8922\xfb\xa5$#P\xaeG\xa3\x08\xb57\xfd\x93\xff\xf5\x1c-\xb6\xdbX\xdd^\x9d\xec\xef\x08\xea\x95#\xb0\x11\x14\xe3]\x0f\x84I\xa4z\x19f\x89\x19U\x8e\xc5 \xa9\xcfW#U\xdf\xe7Bs\x1d\x18\xdb\xad\xdc\xa092s\xcc\x1d\xd7Y\xccy\x8a\xbb1\x89\xbb]\xd8\xf6a\xce\xfe\xf5\xa2w\x8e\xd9\x98pt\xad\x99\x17\xe6\xab\xb7\xff\x95\x18\xfe\xa9\xb9\xaa\xa8\xaaJSi\xb4"K6\x96\x85\xa9l\x10\xfe\xa3O\xac\xd0'
```

It seems the code for the actual file is getting sent instead of the information about the file itself.

Comment: A Python program never starts with an `elif`.

Comment: @Klaus D. This is only a segment of my code, the part that deals with the download command.

Comment: But how should someone replicate the problem with only a part of the code that does not run?

Comment: `fileInfo = s.recv(1024)` Why 1024?

Comment: @David Schwartz it was chosen arbitrarily

Comment: @Greg So then you understand that it will read up to 1,024 bytes, not exactly 1,024 bytes? Otherwise, using an arbitrary value would be a disaster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a pretty much code here but there's one thing that, as I suspect, causes all these errors (or at least the error you posted in your edits - server error looks more like just a bug in IPC).

So, doing this

```
fileInfo = s.recv(1024)
...
fSize = int(fileSize) 
fileContent = s.recv(fSize)
f.write(fileContent)
```

and than saying that you have downloaded the file (`print "Download Complete"`) is unfortunately wrong. TCP transmissions do not preserve their borders. Sending 1000 bytes in one `send` does not imply you need only one `recv` to get it all. One TCP message can get fragmented during transmission. Several TCP messages can arrive as one. The only thing guaranteed is no-error in-order delivery.

The last error seems to illustrate the case, you're getting your file size concatenated with a part of the file.

To overcome the situation, I would like to recommend you to read a bit about TCP and [this article about TCP message framing](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2009/04/message-framing.html).